# Show / hide a div PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function showDiv() {
    if (document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display == 'block') {
        document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```
    <div id="hiddenDiv"  style="display:none;" class="quiz" >
    <?php

    if (basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == '?lang=intermediate'):
       echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'intermediate_quiz', true) );
    elseif (basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == '?lang=advanced'):
        echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'advanced_quiz', true) );
    else:
        echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'beginner_quiz', true)     );
    endif;

    ?>

</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

I am currently trying to hide a div in a single.php on wordpress. I have successfully managed to hide it and show the button BUT when I click the button nothing appears/happens.

Anybody know what is going on?

Comment: The code demonstrably works: https://jsfiddle.net/vdv7Lr55/  Do you have an example which shows the problem?

Comment: ReferenceError: showDiv is not defined[Learn More] business-pos:1:1
 onclick https://www.studythenews.com/business-pos/:1:1

Comment: If the function isn't defined, then it isn't defined.  Maybe you defined it in a separate file and forgot to include it?  Maybe there was some other error in your attempt to define it?  Maybe something else is wrong?  The code, as is, works just fine.

Comment: How is your jQuery function being added to the page? Functions.php? Template?

Comment: I haven't added it to any other places apart from the single.php (where the div is located) and the script has been added to the "additional Javascript" in the theme settings.

Comment: I managed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it.

I put the script into the single.php instead of in the "additional Javascript" and below the div instead.

My code:

```
<input type="button" name="quiz" value="Take Quiz" onclick="showDiv()" />
<div id="quiz"  style="display:none;" class="quiz" >


    <?php

    if (basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == '?lang=intermediate'):
       echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'intermediate_quiz', true) );
    elseif (basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == '?lang=advanced'):
        echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'advanced_quiz', true) );
    else:
        echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'beginner_quiz', true) );
    endif;

    ?>

</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
function showDiv() {
if (document.getElementById('quiz').style.display == 'block') {
    document.getElementById('quiz').style.display = 'none';
} else {
    document.getElementById('quiz').style.display = 'block';
}
}
</script>
```